# phantomjs rasterize.js while rendering to pdf not applying styles from external css

Tags: javascript, css, phantomjs

I am trying to render a simple html page to pdf file using rasterize.js example. The html page has reference to an external style sheet. The page is getting displayed properly in browser but the rendered pdf somehow has no styles applied.

Html block :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content" id="parent">
<div class="card">
<h3> TEST STEP 0</h3>
<p>Action : OpenPage Object :  Data : http://newtours.demoaut.com/</p>
<div class="banner" id="banner0">
<img src="css/pass-icon.png" /></div>
<hr>
<div class="card-image" id="image0">
<img src="Snapshots/null_1420981153527.png" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
            All contents copyright 2014. 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```
body {
    font-family: Calibri, Helvetica;   
    background:#E0E0E0;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    color:#333;
    min-height:100%;
}

.header {
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    height:30px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    background:#FFF;
    padding:25px 0px 5px 0px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #CCC;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.content {  
    position:fixed;
    top:62px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    overflow:scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    margin-left:300px;

}

.footer {
    position:fixed;
    height:22px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:#FFF;
    color:888;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-top:5px solid #CCC;
    font-size:12px;
}

.float-left .card {
    float:left;
    width:300px;  
    height:270px;
}

.multi-column {
    columns:300px 3;
    -webkit-columns:300px 3;
}

.card {
    background:#FFF;
    border-bottom:3px solid #BBB;
    padding:0px;
    margin:15px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.card h2 {
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}

.card h3 {
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}

.card p {
    margin:10px;
    font-family:'helvetica', 'arial', 'sans-serif';
    font-size:12px;
    padding:2px;
    display: inline-block;
    background:#339933;
    color:#FFF;
}

.test{
    font-family:'helvetica', 'arial', 'sans-serif';
    background:#339933;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:12px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:3px;
    float:right;
}

.card-image {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:20px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-image:url('ajax-loader.gif');
}

.card-details {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:20px;
    float:right;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.card-image img {
    width:100%;
}

.banner {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    margin:30px;
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.card-image h1, 
.card-image h2, 
.card-image h3, 
.card-image h4, 
.card-image h5, 
.card-image h6 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    margin:0px;
    padding:6px;
    border:none;
}

.rightColumn,
.leftColumn {
    display:inline-block;
    width:49%;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.column {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.image1 {
    background-image:url('ajax-loader.gif');
}

.image2 {
    background-image:url('ajax-loader.gif');
}
```

Rendered pdf :

[image]

Html page in browser:

[image]

Edit: Trying to render to png does apply css

[image]

Comment: What about when you run it with `--local-to-remote-url-access=true`?

Comment: Tried this option ..still without styles C:\Users\amrit\Downloads\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows>phantom
js.exe --local-to-remote-url-access=true examples\rasterize.js test.html final.p
df A4

Comment: Does it show the styles if you rasterize not as pdf but as png? If yes, you can try to change `media="print"`.

Comment: Trying to rasterize as png works [see edit above] , however changing media to print does not work for both png and pdf

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `!important;` tag at the end of all css statements. if that doesn't work use `-webkit-text-fill-color:` instead of `color:` as css statement, similarly for background